# How to get index of textfield array in the form by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a form with dozen of textfield elements. Any change of their values shall execute Javascript function. And until now I know what I shall to do, but I can't detect index of textfield that triggered function. I tried some solution I saw here & there but wasn't successful.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myforma1" target="_self" id="myforma1">
<input name="txtfield" type="text" id="txtfield" onchange="detect_it(this);" value="name of person" size="20" maxlength="25" />
<input name="txtfield" type="text" id="txtfield" onchange="detect_it(this);" value="name of person" size="20" maxlength="25" />
<input name="txtfield" type="text" id="txtfield" onchange="detect_it(this);" value="name of person" size="20" maxlength="25" />
```

...

```
<script>
function detect_it(oo)
{
alert('Index of triggered element is: ' + oo.index);
/* rest of code */
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that index is not a property of the element. It can have differnet indexes depending on context but you can try
Try something like:

```
    function detect_it(oo){
     var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
     for (var i = 0 ; i<inputs.length ; i++){
        if(oo == inputs[i]{
          alert('Index of triggered element is: ' + i);
        }   
    }
    //enter code here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks raam86, your code seems like solution I wanted. Just small error was there, I corrected it and it now works in Chrome and FF.

    function detect_it(oo){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('txtfield')
    for (var i = 0 ; i<inputs.length ; i++){
    if(oo == inputs[i]){
    alert('Index of triggered element is: ' + i);
    }  
    }
    }
    /* end */

Comment: @LudusH Nice to know . I corrected answer to reflect solution

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't give all your inputs the same name and id.

However, you can still look for the parent node, then iterate over the parent's children until you found your node to retrieve its index.

Try this getIndex() function:

```
<script>
var getIndex = function (node) {
    for (var i =0;i<node.parentNode.children.length;i++) {
        if (node.parentNode.children[i] === node) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
function detect_it(oo) {
    alert('Index of triggered element is: ' + getIndex(oo));
}
</script>
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkJxV/

edit: corrected code (again) (thx @Felix)

Comment: This will never return true since one element is input and the other is form

Comment: @raam86 I corrected my snippet

Comment: tried but got an error

Comment: Seems still not work. Add a working fiddle.

Comment: `node.parentNode.length` is incorrect.

Comment: Well, it works on firefox, and there: http://jsfiddle.net/p2UJL/, but i'll fix it